# Why runtime becomes zero while n is increasing?

Tags: python, runtime, hardware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lxdg.png)

I coded print runtime of sum from 1 to n
I can't understand why runtime becomes zero while n is increasing, Is it my computer problem?

Comment: Could you please put the text of the code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the accuracy of the clock being used.  Note that when the time is non-zero it is always (approximately) 0.015 - that is the resolution of the clock that time.time() is using.  I believe in python3 you should prefer time.perf_counter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for high resolution timing.